# How to properly login to a web using android code

Tags: android, json, web-services, authentication, android-asynctask

Please help me correcting my mistake on how to properly code an android activity that will login to a web, and when it successfully logged in, It can start viewing the content of that web portal?

Here is my unfinished code, please correct my mistakes. Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.weblogin;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog; // Progress Dialog
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://vo.aimglobalinc.com/control/con_login.asp";
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); // JSON parser class

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            //WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // get intent data
    Intent i1 = getIntent();
    // Selected image id
    i1.getExtras().getInt("login");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i1);

  //setup input fields
    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
  //setup buttons
    mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
  //register listeners
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_login:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_register:
                //Intent i = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
                //startActivity(i);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }


        class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            //three methods get called, first preExecture, then do in background, and once do
            //in back ground is completed, the onPost execture method will be called.

            /**
            * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
            * */
            boolean failure = false;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();

            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                String username = user.getText().toString();
                String password = pass.getText().toString();

                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", username));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pword", password));

                    Log.d("request!", "starting");
                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                        //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PortalContents.class);
                        finish();
                        //startActivity(i);
                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    }else{
                        Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                        //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;

            }
            /**
            * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
            * **/

            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
                pDialog.dismiss();
                if (file_url != null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }


        }

}
```

Comment: you are trying to implement a web-browser?

Comment: can you narrow this down a bit, which concrete problem are you facing?

Comment: @Satellite SD: NO, I am actually trying to develop an Android application for our company's webpage. Our webpage is http://www.allianceinmotion.com/members.asp

Comment: we have our username and password to our webpage which I want to do login using this android application that I am doing. I have no access to our company's server. I can only do "trial and error" reading from the browser's developer tool. The code that I posted above is doing good when looking on the logcat, our webpage responding. BUt my problem is when I am about to view the content  of the webpage when login the correct username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your server (for eg :- Local IIS Server) to return a response if the login credentials are correct

My Login AsyncTask Code :-

```
private class GetLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            response = null;
            try {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        if(getLogin !=null && getLogin.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
                            getLogin.cancel(true);
                        }

                    }
                });
                progressDialog.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            try{
                String deviceId = CommonString.deviceId;
                String buildVesrsion = CommonString.buildVersion;
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("email", edtEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                map.put("password", edtPassword.getText().toString().trim());
                map.put("deviceID", deviceId);
                map.put("buildV", buildVesrsion);
                map.put("Platform", CommonString.en);
                map.put("deviceTokenId", regId);
                response = CommonFunction.PostRequest("login", map);
            }catch(Exception e){
                response = null;
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            if(response != null && !response.equals("")){
                parseResponse(response);
            }else{

                if(progressDialog != null & progressDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), CommonString.NO_NETWORK, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

I get a "response" from the server, which i parse it using this function :-

```
private void parseResponse(String responce) {
try {


    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(responce);
    rCode = Integer.parseInt(object.getString("rcode"));
    switch (rCode) {

    case 100: // If respose is true do here
        isLoginCorrect = true;
        JSONObject data = object.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONObject userInfo = data.getJSONObject("userInfo");
        break;
    case 101: // Different errors based on the errors you have defined in your server
        isLoginCorrect = false;
        message = object.getString("msg");
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        break;
    case 102:
        isLoginCorrect = false;
        message = object.getString("msg");
        Toast.makeText(Login.this.getApplicationContext(), "There seems to be some trouble with your account, please login again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        break;
    case 103:
        isLoginCorrect = false;
        message = object.getString("msg");
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        break;
    case 104:
        isLoginCorrect = false;
        message = object.getString("msg");
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        break;
    case 105:
        isLoginCorrect = false;
        message = object.getString("msg");
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    isLoginCorrect = false;


}
    }
```

You can do something like this.

Comment: Thanks, Rahul. I will try this code that you gave. Just a quick question: where did you get these "rcode", "data" , "userInfo" and "msg" . Did you just set it? or do you get it from a web browser's developer tool ? Where can you actually get response from the webpage? <http://www.allianceinmotion.com/members.asp>

Comment: do I still can implement it even though I have no access to our company's server? any workarounds?

Comment: These are json objects in the response provided by the server. This is handled in .net. They provide this response.,. I dont handle server side code, so you have to ask someone else about how to do this, Sorry